# SpecialFolder.Personal location

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, filesystems

I am saving a file to `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` in Xamarin. It appears to succeed, because I can immediately pull data from the file. However, I cannot browse and find this file on my phone. Where exactly is this exclusive `Personal` folder?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` type maps to the path `/data/data/[your.package.name]/files`. This is a private directory to your application so you won't be able to see these files using a file browser unless it has root privileges.

You can inspect these files through adb through the following commands:

```
adb shell
run-as your.package.name
cd files
```

Comment: Is there a way by which I can create user accessible files?

Comment: @Arti maybe `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` should work for user accessible files

Comment: @JustAMartin according to the method doc of `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` it is equivalent to `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`