# Accessing files in the Android.Specialfolder.Personal folder of an emulated device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, filesystems, emulation

I'm creaing a log file in the `Specialfolder.Personal` folder.

I found a similiar question about this here: [SpecialFolder.Personal location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396105/specialfolder-personal-location)

The difference to this linked question is that I'm not using a real device, but instead I only work with the Xamarin Android Player to create emulators.

Can I somehow access files in the `Specialfolder.Personal` folder of my emulator?

Comment: You can access the _Xamarin Android Player_ through the `adb` as it is mentioned in the linked SO post

Comment: You were on the right track yourself. Simply use `adb` as mentioned in the post you linked to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Android Device Monitor to browse emulator file systems. Visual Studio has a convenient method of quickly opening this from the toolbar:

[image]

Select your emulator and browse for the files

[image]

[Source](https://xamarinhelp.com/accessing-files-emulators/)