# How to access xamarin Android environment.personal system folder?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am just working with sqlite DB. My DB location is system.environmet.specialfolder.personal 
So how can access this folder

Comment: Take a look at the Xamarin documentation, it's pretty comprehensive. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can create a connection to an SQLite DB located in `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`:

```
public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
{
    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "mySQLite.db"); // change mySQLite.db for your SQLite db filename
        // Create the connection
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        // Return the database connection
        return conn;
    }
}
```

With

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i want see where is my "mysqlite.db" file. Is it possible to access this file??

Comment: Because mobile applications operate in a sandbox, you can only access your SQLite database from within your app. If all you're after is to see the path, you can take a look at the content of the `path` variable. However, you cannot, for instance, use a file browser to get to the database, or access the database from a different app.

Comment: You may also find the answers to this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396105/specialfolder-personal-location