# Isolated Storage in Environment.SpecialFolder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to understand what should I use if I need to save a file in standard isolated storage.
For iOS I have "Documents" and "Library". "Documents" can I use to see it in iTunes, "Library" is "isolated". (Xamarin documentation)
I found, that "Documents" I can use as

> Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments

and "Library" as

> Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources

But for Android I have an error, if i use Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources because it's not exists in Android.

What should I use to save my files in "isolated" storage for Android? Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments? Or something else?

What I found for iOS:

> Desktop= /Documents/Desktop
>   MyDocuments= /Documents
>   MyDocuments= /Documents
>   Favorites= /Library/Favorites
>   MyMusic= /Documents/Music
>   MyVideos= /Documents/Videos
>   DesktopDirectory= /Documents/Desktop
>   Fonts= /Documents/.fonts
>   Templates= /Documents/Templates
>   ApplicationData= /Documents/.config
>   LocalApplicationData= /Documents
>   InternetCache= /Library/Caches
>   CommonApplicationData= /usr/share
>   ProgramFiles= /Applications
>   MyPictures= /Documents/Pictures
>   CommonTemplates= /usr/share/templates
>   Resources= /Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Android:**

`Personal & MyDocuments` Special folders map to: `/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files`

We can store files in any of the above directories. None of them can be accessed by other app, nor user can access them outside the world unless the phone is rooted.

For more detail on this, please have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237414/what-is-the-best-environment-specialfolder-for-store-application-data-in-xamarin/).