# CrossPlatform Xamarin forms : How to create PDF file in local storage

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Hello I am trying to create a PDF file with using a crossplatform APP made by net standard 2.0 Xamarin forms.

I have a photo stream taken by camera and I want to add it to my pdf

```
// here i check and grant permission


if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{

                        PhotoImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
                        Stream a = photo.GetStream();
                        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "test.pdf");

                        Document document = new Document();

                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                        {
                            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
                            document.Open();
                            using (var imageStream = photo.GetStream())
                            {
                                var image = Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
                                document.Add(image);
                            }
                            document.Close();
                        }

                    }
```

The file test.pdf isn't created in the path :

"/data/user/0/com.companyname.XXX/files/.config/test.pdf"

or at least I can't see it when i check in my phone.

I tested also the path :
"/data/user/0/com.companyname.XXX/files/test.pdf"

please help .

**Edit : I am using iTextSharp**

Comment: You can use `bool doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);` to check if the file exist.

Comment: Yes, actually the file does exist I just couldn't see it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241426/11328573

Answer (score 0):

You can use iTextSharp NuGet to do this.
Or first you can try to create a single file in single project page, like MainActivity.cs